# Using rvalue reference to increase readability

Tags: c++, rvalue-reference

I am accessing points in a `std::vector<std::vector<bool>> grid;` randomly, by doing long calculations:

```
int x = [long to read calculation];
int y = [long to read calculation];

grid[x][y] = true;
```

While it might be a minor improvement, I want to get rid of the intermediate `x` and `y`, however I would like to preserve readability. If I were to declare them as rvalue references, would this improve the code? If not is there something else I can do?

```
int&& x = [long to read calculation];
int&& y = [long to read calculation];

grid[x][y] = true;
```

Comment: What "minor improvement" do you gain from removing `x` and `y`? Have you tested to see what performance gain (if any) there is? Did you compare assembly files to check if the compiler isn't already making a similar optimization for you?

Comment: *"I want to get rid of the intermediate x and y, [...] If I were to declare them as [...]"* -- if they are declared, then you have not gotten rid of them.

Comment: What improvement do you believe this will perform? RValue references aren't magic; they are still references, and they can still extend the lifetime of temporaries much like a `const` reference can -- which is what it sounds like you're doing here. More importantly, `int`s are trivial types to copy, so it's even less clear what improvement you hope to see from an r-value reference. By-value integers are usually better for register stores, rather than references which often perform indirection. As a general rule-of-thumb: don't try to be clever when you don't have to be.

Comment: No I haven't checked if it actually makes a difference. It just seemed like a reasonable thing to try to optimize since I was doing it many times. @Human-Compiler also makes a great point I should have remembered. I recently realized that passing base types like int as const references to functions was pointless because a copy would go just as fast. And I guess this is pretty much the same case.